# Lazy map function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way of making `map` lazy? Or is there another implementation of it built-in in Python?

I want something like this to work:

```
from itertools import count

for x in map(lambda x: x**2, count()):
    print x
```

Of course, the above code won't end, but I'd like just to enter any condition (or more complex logic) inside the `for` and stop at some point.

Comment: See here: [Know when to be Lazy](http://davywybiral.blogspot.com/2008/08/python-know-when-to-be-lazy.html).  In short: either use generator expressions or use the itertools module.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Nice link. In fact, other than doing `x*2` instead of `x**2`, the blog is pretty much perfectly tailored to this question!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Very nice article. Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) on Python 2.x or upgrade to Python 3.x

You can also just use a simple generator expression that is far more pythonic:

```
foo = (x**2 for x in count())
```

Comment: +1 for recommending the generator expression. Wherever you need `lambda`, `map()` isn't a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried to make a simpler code sample for the question (when using `map`).

Answer (score 4):

`itetools.imap` is lazy.

```
In [3]: itertools.imap?
Type:       type
String Form:<type 'itertools.imap'>
Docstring:
imap(func, *iterables) --> imap object

Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
each of the iterables.  Like map() except that it returns
an iterator instead of a list and that it stops when the shortest
iterable is exhausted instead of filling in None for shorter
iterables.
```